# Как переносить div из одного в другой без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Например у меня есть логотип при определенных условиях (например ширина/высота экрана) мне нужно перенести его в другой div.
Обычно я делал так:

```
if(window.innerWidth <= 990){
    $('.logo').prependTo('.div');
}
```

Но для того чтобы изменения вошли в силу когда меняешь ширину экрана нужно перезагружать страницу.

Comment: В чём проблема "запомнить" это через `localStorage` или `sessionStorage`?

Comment: "Но для того чтобы изменения вошли в силу когда меняешь ширину экрана нужно перезагружать страницу.", а в каких случаях это может произойти то?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver